# Mediation - why are effects multiplied and not simply additive?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, causality, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

Very simple question: why are effects in path analysis or mediation multiplied and not simply additive?

Imagine the effect of $X \rightarrow Z$ is 2 and the effect of $Z \rightarrow Y$ is 4, then

the **total effect** of $X \rightarrow Y$ will be $2 \times 4 =8$.

**My question is why not $2 + 4$?**

Similarly, if $X$ has a direct effect on $Y$ (as in Figure 2), let's say 3, then the total effect will be $3 + (2 \times 4) = 11$

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a good question, which one might elaborate as: "why do *effects* multiply but *paths* add?"

Comment: good point -- I would love to know why

Comment: Historically, SEM folk have been interested in a) analytically tractable modeling assumptions like linearity, and b) the relationship between graphs and full data correlation matrices. They also like to think of paths as mechanisms transmitting effects. Then I suspect the only way to maintain a and b is to make these assumptions about effects and paths.

Comment: I find this Pearl paper quite useful: http://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r409-corrected-reprint.pdf The introduction notes succinctly the relationship between a. (linearity, homogeneous effects, etc.) and b. (learning about structure of effects via partial correlations). The examples are also interesting, but not apropos your question.

Comment: thanks. I'm currently studying Perl'S "Causal Inference in Statistics A Primer". But its quite different from the traditional path / SEM literature. What about the answer of @casualcausality? what do you think?

Comment: cc's definition of 'effect' should be familiar from the primer: the 'effect' is that E[Z | do(X=x+1)] - E[Z | do(X=x)] = 2. (No matter what x value you start at). So how to make that true? Assume that E[Z | X] is $\alpha + X\beta$, i.e. linear per SEM. The effect must be the multiplier $\beta$ (not the addition $\alpha$). Why? Subtract E[Z | do(X=x+1)] = $\alpha + (x+1)\beta = \alpha + x\beta + \beta$ from E[Z | do(X=x)] = $\alpha + x\beta$. You get $\beta$. That's why it's the effect.

Answer (score 1):

First let's make clear what effect means in this case (I will consider linear dependencies).
If $X$'s effect on $Z$ is 2, this means that changing $X$ by 1 unit changes $Z$ 2 units.
For $Y$, a 1 unit change in $Z$ will result in a change of 4. I.e., When $X$ changes 1 unit then $Z$ changes by 2 units and $Y$ changes 4 units for **each** unit $Z$ has changes, which is $2\times4=8$.

The second example follows the same way of thinking.

Comment: Thank you, could expand a bit?

Comment: Expand on what? Could you elaborate what you want?